# Install font to system programmatically in Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, fonts

I know, if I want to use a font, that already exists in system, I can set it, for example, this way (1):

```
[[_someButton cell] setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"SomeAlreadyInstalledFontName" size:s]];
```

I also know, I can use a custom font from my project resources someway like that (2):

```
NSFont* someCustomFont = (NSFont*)[fontConverter fontFromBundle:@"SomeCustomFontName" withHeight:someHeight];

[[_someButton cell] setFont:someCustomFont(12)];
```

fontConverter is my class, that has a method with this signature:

```
- (CTFontRef) fontFromBundle : (NSString*) fontName withHeight : (CGFloat) height;
```

It works, however I want, instead of using method (2), install my custom font to system and work with it like (1).

So is it possible to do this: check, if custom font is installed in system, if no, then install it, when the application is launched/being installed?

Comment: You just have to copy the font file to `/Library/Fonts`. Of course, you need permissions/entitlements.

Comment: Do you need your font to be available to *other* apps? Or do you just want to make it somewhat more automatic for your app to find its own fonts?

Comment: I want the same thing for my mac app. Did you find any proper solution? Please post if you are done with it.

Answer (score 1):

> File > Add Files to "Your Project Name"

then move your file to supporting files and be sure that you selected right target for your app and check that following paths:

> Select your project from project navigator> Build Phases> Copy Bundle
>   Resources

if your font appears there it means you did everything correct. The last step is add your font to .plist file:

> Select your info.plist add an array Fonts provided by application and
>   add your font in it as a string

It worked in my case and hope it will help you, too. For further information you may examine this: [Adding custom fonts](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

Comment: I guess, that works for IOS only, not for OSX.

Comment: There may some differences between font file name and font name. Did you check it?